# How to remove response header in lighttpd configuration

Tags: http, lighttpd, http-headers, setenv

There is mod_setenv for **adding**:

```
setenv.add-response-header = ( "Header" => "value" )
```

But I can't find anything to remove response headers.

I have to be sure, that my content is not cached by mobile operator proxies. On Apache I was doing it with:

```
<Directory "/path/to/dir">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate"
    Header add Pragma "no-cache"
    Header unset Last-Modified
    RequestHeader unset If-Modified-Since
</Directory>
```

How can I do that in lighttpd?

Answer (score 1):

This won't necessarily remove the Last-Modified header, but the end result may be similar to what you are looking for:

```
expire.url = ("" => "modification" )
etag.use-inode = "disable"
etag.use-mtime = "disable"
etag.use-size = "disable"
static-file.etags = "disable"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It does a bit. It just removed Etag header from HTTP response (which I should remove while using Apache too - I guess)